# How to use text file to store as data

Tags: java, for-loop

I am to use data stored in a text file. The top number is how many loops we are supposed to print out to each assigned number to shape. If there are duplicates, detect the amount of duplicates and output if any. I was able to print out data, but it does not start from the initial count of 0 and is supposed to repeat the same data if the file has the same corresponding number to shape. For example:

```java
public class Assignment10 {
    public void printInfo(Shape[] sh, Circle newCircle, Rectangle newRectangle, Square newSquare, Ellipse newEllipse) {
        System.out.println("========BEGIN: printInfo()========");
        for (int i = 0; i < sh.length; i++)
            System.out.printf(i + ": " + sh[i] + "\n");
        System.out.printf("\n");
        newCircle.toRevIdxString();
        newRectangle.toRevIdxString();
        newSquare.toRevIdxString();
        newEllipse.toRevIdxString();
        System.out.println("========END: printInfo()========");
    }

    public void detectDup_CorrectType(Shape[] sh, Circle c, Rectangle r, Square s, Ellipse e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sh.length; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sh.length; j++)
                if (sh[i].equals(sh[j])) {
                    System.out.println("Duplicate detected:");
                    System.out.println(i + ": " + sh[i]);
                    System.out.println(j + ": " + sh[j]);
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
```

the text file data I have is

```
5
1
2.5
2
4
3
3
5
2
6
5.3
1
3.2
```

In my console it prints

```
========BEGIN: printInfo()========
0: null
1: Circle with (2.50) has Perimeter=15.71 and Area=19.63
2: Rectangle with (4.00, 3.00) has Perimeter=14.00 and Area=12.00
3: Square with (5.0) has Perimeter=20.0 and Area=25.0
4: Rectangle with (6.00, 5.30) has Perimeter=22.60 and Area=31.80
5: Circle with (3.20) has Perimeter=20.11 and Area=32.17
6: null
7: null
8: null
9: null

Circle Reverse Idx List-> 
[1, 5]
Rectangle Reverse Idx List-> 
[2, 4]Square Reverse Idx List-> 
[3]
Ellipse Reverse Idx List-> 
[]
========END: printInfo()========
```

When it should print

```
========BEGIN: printInfo()========
0: Circle with (2.50) has Perimeter=15.71 and Area=19.63
1: Rectangle with (4.00, 3.00) has Perimeter=14.00 and Area=12.00
2: Square with (5.00) has Perimeter=20.00 and Area=25.00
3: Rectangle with (6.00, 5.30) has Perimeter=22.60 and Area=31.80
4: Circle with (2.50) has Perimeter=15.71 and Area=19.63
Circle Reverse Idx List->[0, 4]
Rectangle Reverse Idx List->[1, 3]
Square Reverse Idx List->[2]
Ellipse Reverse Idx List->[]
========END: printInfo()========
Duplicate detected:
0: Circle with (2.50) has Perimeter=15.71 and Area=19.63
4: Circle with (2.50) has Perimeter=15.71 and Area=19.63
========BEGIN: printInfo()========
0: Circle with (2.50) has Perimeter=15.71 and Area=19.63
1: Rectangle with (4.00, 3.00) has Perimeter=14.00 and Area=12.00
2: Square with (5.00) has Perimeter=20.00 and Area=25.00
3: Rectangle with (6.00, 5.30) has Perimeter=22.60 and Area=31.80
4: Circle with (2.50) has Perimeter=15.71 and Area=19.63
Circle Reverse Idx List->[0, 4]
Rectangle Reverse Idx List->[1, 3]
Square Reverse Idx List->[2]
Ellipse Reverse Idx List->[]
========END: printInfo()========
```

I have all the other methods in their respective classes. I am hoping the problem lies here where I have posted the printInfo.

If I need to add the full code that includes the main I will.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Assignment10 at = new Assignment10();
    int no, i = 0;
    Shape[] shapes = new Shape[10];
    Circle newCircle = new Circle();
    Rectangle newRectangle = new Rectangle();
    Square newSquare = new Square();
    Ellipse newEllipse = new Ellipse();
    File input = new File("input01.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        no = sc.nextInt();
        switch (no) {
        case 1:
            double rad = sc.nextDouble();
            shapes[i] = new Circle(rad);
            newCircle.idx.add(i);
            break;
        case 2:
            double len = sc.nextDouble();
            double brd = sc.nextDouble();
            shapes[i] = new Rectangle(len, brd);
            newRectangle.idx.add(i);
            break;
        case 3:
            float side = sc.nextFloat();
            shapes[i] = new Square(side);
            newSquare.idx.add(i);
            break;
        case 4:
            float a = sc.nextFloat();
            float b = sc.nextFloat();
            shapes[i] = new Ellipse(a, b);
            newEllipse.idx.add(i);
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    at.printInfo(shapes, newCircle, newRectangle, newSquare, newEllipse);
    at.detectDup_CorrectType(shapes, newCircle, newRectangle, newSquare, newEllipse);
    at.printInfo(shapes, newCircle, newRectangle, newSquare, newEllipse);
}
```

```java
public void toRevIdxString() {
    System.out.println("Ellipse Reverse Idx List-> ");
    System.out.println(idx);
}
```

Comment: It looks like method `toRevIdxString()` is not printing what you expect it to print. So why do you think the problem is in method `printInfo`? Also, in the text file data that you posted in your question, there are no duplicates. The second circle has a radius of 3.2 while the first circle has a radius of 2.5. Try to post a [mcve]. Post a `main` method which calls method `printInfo`. Also post the code for method `toRevIdxString()`.

Comment: Nice to see you again @Abra, I have edited the initial post but I did not do a minimal reproducible. You are correct about the new circle having a radius as 3.2, I was using the the output as reference and I'm assuming that its wrong.

Comment: I think I figured out one of the problems that I was having, but I think what I need to do is find a way to use the first number to be used as how many times the program will loop for shapes and store that into the 0 position.

Comment: I think it is because you allocate 10 spaces for shapes array, and add or not you increment i. So if no = 5, there is no shape but because i is incremented, current shapes[i] will be null. You can add a control to your printinfo() method and not print null values. Or do not increment i in main method if the value is null.